# RadioButtons in Expandable List View

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button, expandablelistview

I'm doing expandable list view with checkboxes predominantly. But in some places i have radio buttons. And i need to be able to choose only one of a radio button. Now i did choosing of all of them. Do i need radio groups or remebemer the last checked button?

Answer (score 0):

Use radio groups.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Structure something like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RadioGroup >
        <ListView>
            <ListItem>
                <TextView/>
                <RadioButton/>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem>
                <TextView/>
                <RadioButton/>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem>
                <TextView/>
                <RadioButton/>
            </ListItem>
        </ListView>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: and what if i need such radio groups in several parent groups of expandable list view? do i need use several radio groups?

Comment: This depends on your data. Group together radio buttons from which only one can be selected. If you have different contextual areas use different groups.
But if you have one control, like rating control from which you select mark from one to five, and you want to share that control with different views, save it as something like rate_control.xml and use it multiple times.

Comment: thanks! and one more question - should i add radio group in getChildView?

Comment: You should add it to appropriate parent layout ... You have to get a reference to it somehow in code. How, it depends on your code.

Comment: no( i tried but, for example, if i do a layout with radio group and 4 buttons and add it for children, every child has 4 buttons..I don't how to change it. I need just 4 children have rado buttons and depend on each other ( if i choose on of them the others get uncheked).

Comment: Try to put like master radiogroup on the parent layer and one radio button on each child.